# I have problem with Tkinter: No display name error

Tags: python

I can't run my python program because i have got this error. I am using Raspbian operating system on my Raspberry Pi 2 and I'm making little 'weather station'. My python version is 2.7.16. But when i tried use python 3.6 it is completely broken. I cant download any package using pip3. Only programs I can run on python3 are very simple programs like 'Hello World'.

```
Error:    _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

**What should i do?**

My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import Adafruit_DHT as dht
import threading
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(40, GPIO.HIGH)

root = tk.Tk()

image = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")

background=Label(root, image=image)
background.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1, relheight=1)

temperature = StringVar()
temperature.set("----"+" °C")
humidity = StringVar()
humidity.set("----"+" %")
temperatureLabel = Label(root, fg="white", background="#00dbde", textvariable=temperature, font=("Helvetica$
temperatureLabel.place(x=580, y=100)

humidityLabel = Label(root, fg="white", background="#00dbde", textvariable=humidity, font=("Helvetica", 40,$
humidityLabel.place(x=580, y=200)
root.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
root.bind("<1>",exit)

def exit():
        root.quit()

def readSensor():
        root.after(2000, readSensor)
        h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22,20)
        temp = "%.1f" %t
        temperature.set(temp+" °C")
        hum = "%.1f" %h
        humidity.set(hum+"  %")

root.after(2000, readSensor)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve]. Do all programs lead to that error message?

Comment: _"What should i do?"_ - the first thing you should do is search this site for that exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter does not install from pip. Try running this in your terminal :

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

For python2 use :

```
sudo apt install python-tk
```

Comment: if i use python2 i have this error. Why? What should i do?